# Filling all datetime columns until certain date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe, representing a daily demand from different products and different stores.

```
     SKU    Store    F  LeadTime    Date    Qty Value   Price   Level   
0   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-22  1   3.99    3.99    45  
1   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-23  0   0.00    0.00    45  
2   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-24  3   11.97   3.99    42  
3   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-25  1   3.99    3.99    41  
4   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-26  0   0.00    0.00    41  


300 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-22  1   4.99    3.99    45  
301 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-23  0   0.00    0.00    47  
302 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-24  4   12.97   3.99    48  
303 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-25  1   3.99    3.99    49
```

Using this example, what I am trying to do is to complete the dataset until `2018-01-31` using conditions:

- The columns: `SKU, Store, F, LeadTime, Date, Level` should be completed filling with last value.
- The columns: `Qty, Value, Price` should be completed filling with 0.

So, my expected output should be like this :

```
     SKU    Store    F  LeadTime    Date    Qty Value   Price   Level   
0   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-22  1   3.99    3.99    45  
1   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-23  0   0.00    0.00    45  
2   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-24  3   11.97   3.99    42  
3   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-25  1   3.99    3.99    41  
4   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-26  1   3.99    3.99   41  
5   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-27  0   0.00    0.00    41  
6   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-28  0   0.00    0.00    41  
7   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-29  0   0.00    0.00    41                                                                
8   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-30  0   0.00    0.00    41  
9   504777      1   135828  11  2018-01-31  0   0.00    0.00    41  

300 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-22  1   4.99    3.99    45  
301 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-23  0   0.00    0.00    47  
302 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-24  4   12.97   3.99    48  
303 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-25  1   3.99    3.99    49
304 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-26  0    0       0       49  
305 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-27  0    0       0      49
306 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-28  0    0       0      49  
307 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-29  0    0       0      49  
307 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-30  0    0       0      49  
307 704777      2   135828  11  2018-01-31  0    0       0      49
```

I tried this:

```
df = df.set_index('Date').groupby(['SKU', 'Store']).date_range(end = '2018-01-31', freq='D').agg({
                                             'F':'last',
                                             'LeadTime':'last',
                                             'Price':0,
                                             'Value':0,
                                             'Qty':0,
                                             'Level':'last'}).reset_index()
```

But this is not corret approach:

```
'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'date_range'
```

PS: Every product have a different Startdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First groupby on `SKU` and `Store`.

At the same time you can create a [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with `start` as the max value of you df and `end` as `2018-01-31`.

**Note** I use list comprehension here for win in terms of speed.

Then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) the columns with `0` as needed.

Finally [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) all groupby dataframes and use [`forwardfill (ffill)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
dfs = [pd.concat([d, pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(start=d['Date'].max(), end=pd.Timestamp(2018,1,31))})], ignore_index=True, sort=False) for _, d in df.groupby(['SKU', 'Store'])]

for df in dfs:
    df[['Qty', 'Value', 'Price']] = df[['Qty', 'Value', 'Price']].fillna(0)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, sort=False).ffill()
```

---

```
print(df)
         SKU  Store         F  LeadTime       Date  Qty  Value  Price  Level
0   504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-22  1.0   3.99   3.99   45.0
1   504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-23  0.0   0.00   0.00   45.0
2   504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-24  3.0  11.97   3.99   42.0
3   504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-25  1.0   3.99   3.99   41.0
4   504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-26  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
5   504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-26  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
6   504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-27  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
7   504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-28  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
8   504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-29  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
9   504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-30  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
10  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-31  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
11  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-22  1.0   4.99   3.99   45.0
12  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-23  0.0   0.00   0.00   47.0
13  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-24  4.0  12.97   3.99   48.0
14  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-25  1.0   3.99   3.99   49.0
15  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-25  0.0   0.00   0.00   49.0
16  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-26  0.0   0.00   0.00   49.0
17  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-27  0.0   0.00   0.00   49.0
18  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-28  0.0   0.00   0.00   49.0
19  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-29  0.0   0.00   0.00   49.0
20  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-30  0.0   0.00   0.00   49.0
21  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0 2018-01-31  0.0   0.00   0.00   49.0
```

Comment: I need to use `groupby(['SKU', 'Store'])`.
Where should I include this ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try `reindex` each group. Then create a list to store each group and create a `DataFrame` from that list.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

dfs = []
for _, d in df.groupby(['SKU', 'Store']):

    start_date = d.Date.iloc[0]
    end_date = start_date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()

    d.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    d = d.reindex(pd.date_range(start_date, end_date))
    d.fillna

    dfs.append(d)

new_df = pd.concat(dfs)

new_df

                 SKU  Store         F  LeadTime  Qty  Value  Price  Level
2018-01-22  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  1.0   3.99   3.99   45.0
2018-01-23  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   45.0
2018-01-24  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  3.0  11.97   3.99   42.0
2018-01-25  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  1.0   3.99   3.99   41.0
2018-01-26  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
2018-01-27       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2018-01-28       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2018-01-29       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2018-01-30       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2018-01-31       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2018-01-22  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  1.0   4.99   3.99   45.0
2018-01-23  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   47.0
2018-01-24  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  4.0  12.97   3.99   48.0
2018-01-25  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  1.0   3.99   3.99   49.0
2018-01-26       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2018-01-27       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2018-01-28       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2018-01-29       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2018-01-30       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2018-01-31       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Then use `ffill` to fill `NaN`.

```
new_df = pd.concat(dfs)
new_df[['Price', 'Qty', 'Value']] = new_df[['Price', 'Qty', 'Value']].fillna(0)
new_df.ffill(inplace=True)
new_df
Out[17]: 
                 SKU  Store         F  LeadTime  Qty  Value  Price  Level
2018-01-22  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  1.0   3.99   3.99   45.0
2018-01-23  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   45.0
2018-01-24  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  3.0  11.97   3.99   42.0
2018-01-25  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  1.0   3.99   3.99   41.0
2018-01-26  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
2018-01-27  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
2018-01-28  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
2018-01-29  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
2018-01-30  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
2018-01-31  504777.0    1.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   41.0
2018-01-22  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  1.0   4.99   3.99   45.0
2018-01-23  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   47.0
2018-01-24  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  4.0  12.97   3.99   48.0
2018-01-25  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  1.0   3.99   3.99   49.0
2018-01-26  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   49.0
2018-01-27  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   49.0
2018-01-28  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   49.0
2018-01-29  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   49.0
2018-01-30  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   49.0
2018-01-31  704777.0    2.0  135828.0      11.0  0.0   0.00   0.00   49.0
```